# Where should I ask my [marvel-cinematic-universe] questions - Science-Fiction or Movies?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation

The [Science-Fiction Stack Exchange has a tag for `[marvel-cinematic-universe]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) with the tag wiki:

> For questions about the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU), the media franchise and shared fictional universe that is centred on a series of superhero films, independently produced by Marvel Studios and based on characters that appear in publications by Marvel Comics. Always use in conjunction with the [marvel] tag and any relevant film tags, e.g. [iron-man-2].

The [Movies Stack Exchange has a tag for `[marvel-cinematic-universe]`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe?tab=Votes) with the tag wiki:

> Use this tag for questions that are related to the fictional universe in which all films and TV shows independently produced by Marvel Studios take place.

Browsing through some of the questions on each site, there seems to be a lot of overlap.

I read the post [Where should I ask questions about science-fiction or fantasy movies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252944/1038757) and it explains:

> - On Movies.SE, the community is built around Movie/TV enthusiasts, so you are going to get an answer from that perspective - people who love movies and/or television.
> - On SciFi.SE, the community is built around enthusiasts of Science Fiction. Answers you get may go into more details into the lore behind a franchise, pulling in from other sources (such as books, comics, and related materials).

So if I understand correctly, any question I have about the Marvel Cinematic Universe would be on topic for either site, it just depends on what audience I'm looking for? I'm hoping for clarification that might apply specifically to the Marvel Cinematic Universe. Both network sites seem to be full of questions asking about motivations of characters and explanations of plot points in the movies, but I can't see clear guidance on when to ask on one or the other.

Some questions that are similar to ones I could ask that I can't tell the difference between:

- Movies

  - [Why does Doctor Strange not bind Thanos in a time loop?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88468/why-does-doctor-strange-not-bind-thanos-in-a-time-loop)
  - [Why does Thanos need *all* the infinity stones?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88463/why-does-thanos-need-all-the-infinity-stones)
  - [Why is Vision so weak?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/why-is-vision-so-weak)
- Scifi

  - [Why do Thanos's punches not kill Captain America or at least cause some mortal injuries?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212078/why-do-thanoss-punches-not-kill-captain-america-or-at-least-cause-some-mortal-i)
  - [Why does The Ancient One think differently about Doctor Strange in Endgame than the film Doctor Strange?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/why-does-the-ancient-one-think-differently-about-doctor-strange-in-endgame-than)
  - [In The Avengers (2012), why does Thanos need Loki?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211291/in-the-avengers-2012-why-does-thanos-need-loki)

These questions asking about the story of Marvel Cinematic Universe films seem to be on topic and successful on either site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're perfectly right: questions about the Marvel Cinematic Universe are on-topic on both of those sites. Each has a very active user base, and plenty of regular users who, between them, are capable of answering almost any on-topic question you may have.

I'd honestly say it comes down to personal preference. There are some users who prefer SciFi.SE, and there are others who prefer Movies.SE. My personal preference is to ask MCU questions on SciFi.SE, simply because it's the most specialised site for them and therefore, in my view, the better fit. For the same reason, I only ask anime questions on Anime.SE, even if SciFi or Movies would accept them.

Of course, it's up to you which site you prefer. The only important thing is that you don't post the same question on both sites. That won't be looked upon too kindly.

Answer (score 2):

> "... guidance on when to ask on one or the other [site(s)]."

When a question of which site to ask on seems close between two or more sites and there appears to be nothing indicated to prefer one over the other it may help to examine the data available.

In this case it seems neck and neck, but it may be (subject to one's interpretation of the results below) that Movies & TV is minutely ahead. Since you joined both sites yesterday it might come down to which one you want to call home; what **other** interests of yours are served by each site.

While this answer is tailored to your question, this method can be applied to the same problem for a different subject - when there's more than one site and both seem equally good how does one choose.

1. Various SEDE queries:

   - "Accumulated reputation [score] for tags":

     - [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1360263/accumulated-reputation-for-tags) 70553
     - [Movies & TV](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/1360263/accumulated-reputation-for-tags?TAG=marvel-cinematic-universe&opt.textResults=true) 37516
   - "Collective answer reputation [score] for tag" (Credit: [Wolf](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404579/3648282)):

     - [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1360304/collective-answer-reputation-for-tag?TAG=marvel-cinematic-universe&opt.textResults=true) 47120
     - [Movies & TV](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/1360304/collective-answer-reputation-for-tag) 24267

     So questions for the tag [marvel-cinematic-universe] scored 23,433 for 2,212 questions (105.936 per question) on Sci-fi & Fantasy and 13,249 for 1,253 questions (105.738 per question) on Movies & TV. Almost identical. If those calculations seem high see the "Hot answers tagged [marvel-cinematic-universe]" lists for [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/marvel-cinematic-universe/hot?filter=all) and [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/marvel-cinematic-universe/hot?filter=all).
   - "Average number of answers per question, time limited":

     When that query is ran (on 2021-July-21) against each site with the parameters:

     QuestionDateFrom: **2019**-01-01 and QuestionDateTill: 2022-01-01
     1.49 A/Q for [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and 1.54 A/Q for [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)

     QuestionDateFrom: **2021**-01-01 and QuestionDateTill: 2022-01-01
     1.34 A/Q for [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and 1.37 A/Q for [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)

     The difference these past several months has narrowed further, essentially you'll get the same number of answers to your question from either site.

     Let's not change ***what*** we ask, let's change ***how*** we ask and be more specific:

     - A direct site search for questions tagged [marvel-cinematic-universe]:

       Sci-fi & Fantasy has:   [2,212](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aquestion) questions, [4,294](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aanswer) answers, with [2,076](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Atrue) answered and [136](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Afalse) unanswered. 1.941 answers per question. 211 watchers.

       Movies & TV has:         [1,253](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aquestion) questions, [2,350](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aanswer) answers, with [1,191](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Atrue) answered and [62](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarvel-cinematic-universe%5D+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Afalse) unanswered. 1.875 answers per question. 185 watchers.

     That method doesn't seem to put us much ahead, but with the large number of people watching (Favorited) on Movies & TV, and the lighter traffic of late, there's more people alerted to new questions.

     If we do a bit of research we discover that on Sci-fi & Fantasy's meta they posted this question: "[Bounties for tag: Marvel Cinematic Universe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6750/110535)" (asked Mar 25 '15), that campaign probably resulted in a temporary increase in the number of questions there.

     Not to be outdone, over at Movies & TV's meta they've had at least two events: "[Topic Challenge: The Marvel Cinematic Universe [completed]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1780/69970)" (asked Apr 25 '15) and "[Topic Challenge: The TV-series of the Marvel Cinematic Universe [completed]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3977/69970)" (asked Aug 26 '17).

     Movies & TV even went a step further, asking "[What to do with the [marvel-cinematic-universe]?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1875/69970)" (should they ensure that every relevant question is so tagged - yes) and "[MCU Tag and defining scope](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1936/69970)" (Scope: anything made by Marvel Studios). The subject is actively discussed and the users are engaged with the topic on that site.

     It's interesting to note that Sci-fi & Fantasy also has a [Marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/marvel/info) tag (4228 questions) in addition to over a dozen more *Marvel** tags with very few questions, but Movies & TV doesn't have a [Marvel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/marvel) tag or any additional *Marvel** tags; other than [marvel-cinematic-universe].

     If there's been any imperfectly tagged questions there's a potential for a greater number of questions than first appears; though Sci-fi & Fantasy's meta users claim that they are alert and proactive against such problems.

     We can check if retagging is occurring with the SEDE query "How to list posts which have a particular tag but didn't have it when originally asked":

     - [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1310297/how-to-list-posts-which-have-a-particular-tag-but-didnt-have-it-when-originally) - 790 questions retagged.
     - [Movies & TV](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/1310297/how-to-list-posts-which-have-a-particular-tag-but-didnt-have-it-when-originally?tagname=marvel-cinematic-universe) - 583 questions retagged.

     Make of the result what you will - either it's more common to forget the tag, requiring it to be added, or indeed the users are more vigilant at ensuring correct tagging. Either way it's approximately a third of the questions, but more than that on Movies & TV.

     On the subject of each site's metas: Sci-fi & Fantasy's meta has [3,151](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion) questions with [6,482](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) answers, while Movies & TV has [1,248](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion) and [2,062](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) respectively. Sci-fi & Fantasy's meta site is approximately three times more utilized than Movies & TV's site.
   - Let's look at some graphs. I edited [rene's query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312996/3648282) for a specific tag's usage over time on Stack Overflow (or any site that has that tag) to permit any tag to be used:

     - [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1438588?string=marvel-cinematic-universe#graph) (tag: marvel-cinematic-universe):

       [image: SEDE query for tag [marvel-cinematic-universe] on Sci-fi & Fantasy]
     - [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1438588?string=marvel-cinematic-universe#graph) (tag: marvel):

       [image: SEDE query for tag [marvel] on Sci-fi & Fantasy]
     - [Movies & TV](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/1438588?string=marvel-cinematic-universe#graph) (tag: marvel-cinematic-universe):

       [image: SEDE query for tag [marvel-cinematic-universe] on Movies & TV]

     The graphs don't change the information that we obtained using the first query above, but they do shed a different light on the numbers. It appears that Sci-fi & Fantasy's higher numbers are derived from an additional two large spikes and a few small spikes.

     There's a consistent, but only slightly higher, number of questions over the years; early on it looks like the "marvel" tag was used, the "marvel-cinematic-universe" tag usage picked up after 2015. It's only in the past year and a half that Movies & TV's questions for the tag have dropped off to a trickle.
   - Another consideration is the *question grading* query (original by [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302970/282094)) which tracks the community's evaluation of new questions as they come in, modified for a reduced date range (and improved resolution) by [Trilarion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342799/282094):

     [Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1125143/historical-question-grades-by-week#graph):

     [image]

     [Movies & TV](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/1125143/historical-question-grades-by-week#graph):

     [image]

     The "question grade" is based on objective measures of community feedback:

     - Good - (Score > 0 or (AnswerCount > 0 and Score = 0)) and !Closed
     - Bad - Score < 0 or Closed
     - Neutral - Score = 0 and !Closed and AnswerCount = 0

     The results for the past five years on Sci-fi & Fantasy have been relatively consistent, on Movies & TV the past year and a half has seen a decline in objectively evaluated "good" questions and an increase in the "bad" ones; allowing the "neutral" number to become more visible.

     One interpretation is, that with the lower number of questions as of late for the tag, that if you ask a good question it will rise to the top and obtain an answer quicker. The data is there, to make your own decision.
2. Search and sort on the listing of [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic):

   [image: Snippet of the listing from "All Sites", sorted by "Traffic".]

   Notice that Sci-fi has 3.095 times more questions and 3.371 times more answers, the percentage answered is the same. Sci-fi has 1.719 times more users, 1.237 times more visitors per day, and **4** times more questions per day. Both sites are of a similar age.

   The difference that most stands apart from the rest is the number of questions per day, presumably the result would be much fewer people able to answer your question and it would be bumped down the front page faster; that may result in greater competition for the HNQ list (which is either good or bad).

   Those facts combined with 211 watchers on Sci-fi & Fantasy versus 185 watchers on Movies & TV ***probably*** leaves more people available to attend to your question faster, if they are among the site's daily visitors.

Make of this method and the data what you wish. When it happens that more than one site seems equally good it sometimes helps to have more than one way to look at the problem. In this case both sites seem equally good, possibly with a slight preference for Movies & TV.

In the end it may well come down to your other interests, if you are only interested in questions and answers that fall [within the scope of Sci-fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then it's probably the better site for you. If your interests expand to the [scope of Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then that's probably the site to prefer for your question and future interests.